# How can I maintain the current state of processing while looping through received serial data?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am writing an application in C# to run on a Windows 10 PC.  This application will control a device under test (DUT) through a serial port.  It will also be controlling several pieces of test equipment under USB and/or Ethernet control (things like digital meters, power supplies, etc).

In C I would create a static variable to hold the current status of processing such as "Looking for delimiter", "Found delimiter", "Found end-of-line", etc.  There is no guarantee that the current buffer has a complete message in it so, while the code is reading as big a block of data as possible, each character needs to be processed one at a time according to the rules of what constitutes a valid message.

I am trying to figure out how to replace the concept of having a static variable with a something else (a class maybe) but I'm just too new to C# to know where to begin.  My code has a function that is called whenever data is received from the serial port.

I would put the code in this question but there's over 15 files spread throughout multiple directories since I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019.  I started with an example serial port program I found on https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners and have been trying to grow my skill set to meet the projects needs.

Any suggestions as to what to Goggle to find a way to process each character based on the current state of the processing?

(I would just write the app in C but that presents a bunch of other problems, mainly figuring out how to write a Windows app in C that can access the serial port.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a static class, and in that class one or more static fields (or call it variables if you want). You don't need a non-static class as long as there's just one device, so start with this to keep it simple while you learn.

As for processing incoming messages;

I would simply buffer the characters by adding them to a string as they come in.

Then, each time more characters have been added, loop and try to eat complete messages from the string. If there's no complete message, then leave the string as is. If there's a complete message, remove the corresponding characters from the start of the string. The loop ends when no more complete messages can be eaten from the start of the string.

Create a simple function to eat one message from the string. That function should take the string as input, and return a possible message and the remaining characters of the input string. That is, the input string minus the characters in the front that made up a complete message. If a complete message was not found, the function should return no message, and the same string as was input.

This way, you don't need to keep advanced parser state while waiting for more characters to arrive. You only need the buffering string that keeps the characters of the yet incomplete message.

Pardon me if I'm being too detailed, but I don't know your level of expertise.